# Referencing a global variable out of a list

Tags: python, database, list, global

I have a list of variables (t0,t1,t2). Each value on this list is also associated with global variable. How do I go about referencing the global variable value by calling from the list. I keep just getting a string I try and reference.

Thank you.
Code:

```
t0 = [5,8]
t1 = [2,7]
t2 = [4,1]
```

The list of the global variable names is

```
listnames('t0','t1','t2')
```

I guess the main question is how do I go from list names to what is shown below using an expression. Eventually, the list will be dynamic in size and I want to always call all the global variables without editing the code.

What I want from the list:

```
list2=[t0,t1,t2]
print(lists)
```

Thanks again..

Comment: `globals()["some_name"]` so `list2 = [globals()[x] for x in list_of_names]`

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't entirely work.

You are trying to add the references to a list but not the object itself?
maybe this would be better off as a dictionary:

```
map = {
"t0": [5,8],
"t1": [2,7],
"t2": [4,1],
}
```

Comment: `map` is a built-in name. Don't use it as a variable name.